# number of element in a cursor after requesting mongodb with node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am doing sole request to mongodb

```
var cursor = db.collection('pages').find({});
```

I want to get the number of element in the cursor. This will help me to close the connection to the database.

Could you help please

Cordially

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of elements in a cursor, use the **[`count()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/)** method. In mongo shell, this can be derived as follows:

```
var cursor = db.collection('pages').find({}),
    numberOfElements = cursor.count();
```

In node.js, you can get the count async as:

```
var numberOfElements = function(db, collectionName, callback){
    db.collection(collectionName, function(e, coll) {
        coll.find({}).count(function (err, count) {
           if (err) return callback(err);
           console.log(count);
           return callback(null, count);
        });
    });
};
```